# How to read attributes in HDF5 file using C++ interface

Tags: hdf5

I have   HDF5 file where the attributes are in below format

```
ATTRIBUTE "dtype" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE 8;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLPAD;
         CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
   DATASPACE  SCALAR
   DATA {
   (0): "waveform"
   }
}
```

I want to retrieve the waveform out of the attributes.I tried the below code snippet but it crashes

```
Group* signalgroup = new Group(outputgroup->openGroup(signalgrpName));
Attribute *attr = new Attribute(signalgroup->openAttribute("dtype"));
DataType  *type = new DataType(attr->getDataType());
H5std_string test;
attr->read(*type, &test); //crashes here
```

Any inputs on how to read this?

Comment: `DataType  *type = new DataType(attr->getDataType());` looks suspect. how about `Datatype type = attr->getDataType()`?

Comment: Tried with Datatype type = attr->getDataType(), still it crashes

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but I stumbled across this question searching something similar. The HDF5 API has an overloaded `attribute.read()` function that takes in a `std::string` by reference (not by pointer).

See here in the documentation: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_attribute.html#a8dae50d14de724c87507cba37f86793d (quoted below)

```
void H5::Attribute::read(const DataType& mem_type, H5std_string& strg) const

Parameters
mem_type    - IN: Attribute datatype (in memory)
strg    - IN: Buffer for read string
```